# Entity Framework/External synchronisation architecture

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, architecture

I have an application which queries a local store of data (currently backed by an XML file), using Linq to Objects. Periodically, another thread in the application will query a remote server for updated data, and if it exists, will download all of the remote data, deserialise it and replace the local objects with newly deserialised ones before saving the new XML to disk.

I have decided to replace the XML file with a SQLite database, and I intend to use Entity Framework to interact with it. This has prompted me to re-look at the way external changes are applied, and I've decided that only data where the remote entities `updated_at` property is newer than the local entity will be updated (rather than the current approach of replacing the whole data set)

So I must write a method to download the external changes and update or insert the relevant entities into the SQLite database.

What I don't understand is where, in architectural terms, this method should sit. My (potentially naive) thinking is that a generic `UpdateFromRemoteObjects<T>(List<T> updatedItems)` method could sit in the `DbContext` class, and would accept a list of entities and update the appropriate `DbSet`. But this feels like it may be too closely coupled to the `DbContext`. Should I use a repository to provide a layer to implement this? Or is another application architecture more appropriate?

Comment: Well, you wrote that you already have some queries in your project. Where are they placed in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many people start with [**CRC**](http://google.com/search?q=crc%20cards) when designing components: **Classes** have **Responsibilities** and **Collaborators**

First consider the single responsibility principle: a class with two or more responsibilities is probably doing too much. This is your reason for not putting the method on the DbContext: this updating stuff is a new distinct responsibility, so create a class for it.

I can see this class doing 2 things: QueryRemoteServerForChanges and UpdateLocalObjects.

Now consider its Collaborators. it seems to need two: an instance of DbContext for the local changes, and a instance of whatever gives access to the remote data.

So not a repository no; and not a layer; but definitely a class with a responsibility.